# how does increment operator work in javascript? directly assigns value to variable?

Tags: javascript, increment

how does below code give result as 10

```js
var myVar = 2;
myVar = ++myVar + myVar++ + myVar--;
console.log(myVar);
```

and when directly given as below without assigning to myVar give result as 3 in javascript?

```js
var myVar = 2;
++myVar + myVar++ + myVar--;
console.log(myVar);
```

Comment: Summary: 1. Convert its operand to a number. 2. Add 1 to the operand. 3. Assign the incremented value to the operand.

Comment: The first code block evaluates to `myVar = 3 + 3 + 4; // 10`, so we assign the result of adding all the operands (those being `++myVar`, `myVar++`, and `myVar--`). The second one evaluates to `3 + 3 + 4`, but that does nothing with the calculation, so all we see is the side effects of running `++` and `--` on `myVar`, where it ends up as `3`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for all of you for taking your time to provide an explanation here for my query

Answer (score 3):

There are two main factors we need to analyze:

Pre-Increment - The variable is first incremented, and then its value is used:

```
++x
```

Post-Increment - The variable value is first used, and then the value is incremented:

```
x++
```

With the first example:

```
var myVar = 2;
myVar = ++myVar + myVar++ + myVar--;
console.log(myVar);
```

The `++myVar` increments the value from 2 to 3 first, so the value `3` is used. Then, for `myVar++`, the value 3 is used first, and then it is incremented to 4. For `myVar--`, the `4` is used, and then the value decrements from 4 to 3.

In the end, the expression will be: 3 + 3 + 4 = `10`

For the second example:

```
var myVar = 2;
++myVar + myVar++ + myVar--;
console.log(myVar);
```

The individual +'s between the `myVar` are doing nothing. They are adding them together, but there is no variable storing that value. So the only thing that line does is apply the changes of `++myVar`, `myVar++`, and `myVar--` to `myVar`, giving it a value of `3` (from 2 to 3 to 4 to 3).

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Teemu said. Reading the documentation is really helpful.
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment)

Maybe this helps also to understand this.

```js
var myVar = 2;
myVar += myVar++;
console.log(myVar);
```